# Can any for loop be vectorized in python(numpy)?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, vectorization

I have been recently getting into python optimization by learning about broadcasting and vectorization. I would say I have got the basics down, but there are just some for loops I am uncapable of vectorizing. My question is: is it possible to convert any python for loop into a C++ for loop using numpy?

As an example:

```
import numpy as np
N = 10
A = np.eye(4) * 0.5
r = np.eye(4)
W = np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(1), N)                            
r_t = r[None]
for i in range(N):
    z    = np.trace(A @ r)                                           
    temp = r * W[i] * z                                                                            
    r_t  = np.concatenate((r_t, temp[None]))                           
    r    = temp
```

The code is an example, and it is not supposed to do anything in particular (aside from returning r_t as a (N, 4,4) array).
W is an array of N values randomly picked from a normal distribution; A is identity matrix scaled by 0.5, and r is initially the identity matrix.

The problem I am finding is that I want "r" to be updated at the end of every loop, so that the value of "z" is different at every loop as well. Is there any way one could vectorize a loop of this sort?

Comment: With `numpy`: No, at least not efficiently. Vectorization assumes that all arrays for the calculation already exist in memory. With [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/): Yes. The main problem in the sample code, however, is `np.concatenate` (use a `list` to collect arrays and convert the entire `list` at the end, or pre-allocate the result array and write result slices). `z = np.einsum('jj,jj->', A, r)` can calculate the trace faster.

Comment: Hi, im sorry for the ignorance here, but could you maybe give me another explanation on how using a list could help in this case? ( I will also look into numba righ now).

Comment: `np.concatenate` create a new array each time with a copy of *r_t*. Appending to a `list` avoids this unnecessary work.

Comment: ohh, I see what you mean, definitely. although, the for loop would still persist if I keep using only numpy.

Comment: Obviously not; you can do lots of stuff in loops that can't be done with `numpy` whole-array methods.  If there's something inherently serial about the loop (new value dependent on previous), it's hard - unless you can use something like `np.cumsum` and other `ufunc` accumulate.  `numpy` vectorization is easiest when there isn't an implicit order, where (in theory) all elements could be acted on at once ('parallel' versus 'serial').